# How to save the position of drag and drop ( image,button,text ,paragraph ) in php,mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

**How to save the  position of drag and drop ( image,button,text ,paragraph ) in php,mysql**

Comment: Provide some details, please.

Comment: Give us some table structures, you should at least try to explain what you have tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If updating position live: use JQuery + AJAX to send coordinates (more complex)

If updating position after clicking a submit button:

1) make hidden html fields:

```
<form action="mySubmitScript.php" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' id='textfieldX' name='textfieldX'/>
    <input type='hidden' id='textfieldY' name='textfieldY'/>
</form>
```

2) on jQuery element move event, set hidden html field value:

```
$('#textfieldX').val(XCordinateVar);
$('#textfieldY').val(YCordinateVar);
```

3) $_POST to get values:

```
$x = $_POST['textfieldX'];
$y = $_POST['textfieldY'];
```

4) sql to store:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($x, $y);
```

Comment: Need to update in live using AJAX??

Comment: yeah. AJAX might be a little too hard to learn for some users.

It means you can send information to database without refreshing webpage.